# Flexible array in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

Im trying to have an unlimited array in C to store some data. My header file stock.h looks like this

```
#ifndef STOCK_H
#define STOCK_H

typedef struct {
    char* id;
    char* descripcion;
    int precio;
} tAppliance;

typedef struct {
    int cantidad;
    tAppliance electrodomestico;
} tElectroStock;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    tElectroStock *electrodomesticos;
} tStock;

void tstock_init(tStock *stock);

void tstock_add(tStock *stock, tAppliance item, int cantidad);

#endif
```

My stock.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stock.h"

void tstock_init(tStock *stock) {
    stock->size = 0;
    stock->capacity = 10;
    stock->electrodomesticos = malloc(sizeof(tElectroStock) * stock->capacity);
}

void tstock_add(tStock *stock, tAppliance item, int cantidad) {
    if(stock->size >= stock->capacity) {
        stock->capacity = stock->capacity * 2;
        stock->electrodomesticos = realloc(stock->electrodomesticos, sizeof(tElectroStock) * stock->capacity);
    }
    tElectroStock t;
    t.cantidad = cantidad;
    t.electrodomestico = item;
    stock->size++;
    stock->electrodomesticos[stock->size] = t;  
}
```

And finally my main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stock.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    tStock t; // Creamos nuestra variable de stock
    tstock_init(&t); // Iniciamos el stock
    tAppliance item;
    item.descripcion = "Television SONY";
    item.id = "apeid9";
    item.precio = 20;
    tstock_add(&t, item, 1);
    tstock_add(&t, item, 1);
}
```

As you can see on my main function I try to add 2 items to tStock. however adding the second item seems to crash the whole applicattion and no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable all warnings, and treat every single one of them as error. That way you could've found the issue with the member not being a pointer that's already been mentioned yourself.

Check the return value of library functions like `malloc` and `realloc` for errors and handle them appropriately.

Finally, you'll want to swap these two lines:

```
stock->size++;
stock->electrodomesticos[stock->size] = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile with `-Wall` you'll be warn:

```
test.c: In function ‘tstock_init’:
test.c:634:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     stock->electrodomesticos = malloc(sizeof(tElectroStock) * stock->capacity);
     ^
test.c:634:32: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
     stock->electrodomesticos = malloc(sizeof(tElectroStock) * stock->capacity);
                                ^
test.c: In function ‘tstock_add’:
test.c:640:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘realloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         stock->electrodomesticos = realloc(stock->electrodomesticos, sizeof(tElectroStock) * stock->capacity);
         ^
test.c:640:36: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘realloc’
         stock->electrodomesticos = realloc(stock->electrodomesticos, sizeof(tElectroStock) * stock->capacity);
```

Add to `stock.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

You must also switch instruction as below:

```
stock->electrodomesticos[stock->size] = t; 
stock->size++;
```

Otherwise your code is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when `stock->size++ == stock->capacity`

Comment: Edited to make it clear where to add the include. I hope you don't mind :)